# Rails 5 Migration - Missing reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm not sure what I'm missing - I recently moved my `Product` category from being a static enum to being a table, so I needed to modify reference.

I'll combine my numerous migrations that build the `Tasks` table that I need to have a reference to the `Product` table

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :task_name
      t.text :comment
      t.datetime :task_start_date
      t.datetime :task_end_date
      t.references :project

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddDocumentsToTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :tasks, :document, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :tasks, :product, foreign_key: true
  end
end


class AddClientIdToTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :tasks, :client, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Now for the fresh schema (reduced)

```
 create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "product_name"
    t.text "product_description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "client_id"
  end

  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "task_name"
    t.text "comment"
    t.datetime "task_start_date"
    t.datetime "task_end_date"
    t.bigint "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "product"
    t.bigint "document_id"
    t.boolean "completed"
    t.integer "client_id"
    t.index ["document_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_document_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_project_id"
  end
```

I actually have no clue where `t.integer "product"` is coming from on the tasks folder. I've looked all over.

It's currently breaking all integrations/seeding because of a warning such as:
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Product(#69974683871240) expected, got 1 which is an instance of Integer(#13017840)`

I assume it's something very simple I'm missing but since it's the very redundant code I don't quite know why it works for document/project, but not the product.

Just in case:
Product migration

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :product_name
      t.text :product_description
      t.references :client
      t.references :task

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

end**

**Update**

Not answering this until I fully understand why, but it seems like I misunderstood what `rails db:reset` did. Once I dropped/created/migrated/seed step-by-step the entire DB structure kicked in and the new schema took place.

it seems db:reset was *only* using the logic within my Schema.rb file.

Comment: Is your problem still up ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `schema.rb` is used as cache for your migrations. So if you change a migrations file already migrated, the modifications won't appear. You have to delete your `schema.rb` content and then reset your database.